# Info Window looks different

Tags: html, google-maps

Has anyone noticed the info window and markers have recently changed (for the worse)! I initially thought it was Internet Explorer, but I checked it across all devices (IE10, iPad, iPhone.  I also checked old files from a few months ago and it's changed there too.  Some info windows show all the intended info, and some show a narrow info window with a scroll bar.  I tried maxWidth, but regardless of what number I put in there, the info window doesn't get any larger.  If I put in a number like 50, then the info window will get very narrow (with the scroll bar).
I guess I wonder if there is a way to make the info Window a static size that I know will be large enough to display the information I need it to display.
Any help/guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you using [Google Maps](http://maps.googel.com) or the [Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)?

Comment: u can also just override the css as described here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/26639869/1105937

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The experimental version 3.14 has undergone a a new look. If you do not specify the version when you load the javascript you will receive the experimental version by default. To use the release version, specify "v=3" in the url

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=false
```

Please not that this would only be a temporary solution until the experimental version goes live in November.

Comment: Thanks that did make it work like it used to.  So would there be a solution once November rolls around to make the infoWindow not do what it's doing (randomly shrinking and adding a scroll bar)?

Comment: I think then you can set google.maps.visualRefresh global property to false, check the link for more details https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#EnableVisualRefresh

Answer (score 1):

As announced the ["visual refresh"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#VisualRefresh) is now live for the Google Maps Javascript API v3 if you are using the "experimental" version (no version number in the API load).