# How do I make Google Maps info windows fit the contents perfectly in all browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, google-maps

You can see in the below example that the maps "info windows" render differently in every browser (sometimes the content is cut off, sometimes the info windows have scroll bars).

Anyone know how to make my Google Maps "info windows" fit the content perfectly in all browsers?

Example html:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>test</title>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
<script>
function map_initialize() {
 var myMapInfo = [
  {
   id: "122",
   name: "Test1 Caravan Park",
   latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.43746, 144.87258)
  },
  {
   id: "121",
   name: "Test2 Family Holidays",
   latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.38098, 144.91090)
  },
  {
   id: "123",
   name: "Test3 Frankston Holiday Park",
   latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.17425, 145.14136)
  },
  {
   id: "125",
   name: "Test4 Holiday Park",
   latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.33165, 144.98331)
  },
  {
   id: "124",
   name: "Test5 Port Harbour Caravan Park",
   latlng: new google.maps.LatLng(-38.24634, 145.24469)
  },
 ];
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), {
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
  zoom: 6,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
  mapTypeControl: false,
  mapTypeControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
  },
  panControl: false,
  panControlOptions: {
   position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
  },
  zoomControl: false,
  zoomControlOptions: {
    style: google.maps.ZoomControlStyle.SMALL,
    position: google.maps.ControlPosition.BOTTOM_LEFT
  }
 });
 
 // Display multiple markers on a map
 var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(), marker, i;

 for (var i = 0; i < myMapInfo.length; i++) {

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   position: myMapInfo[i].latlng,
   map: map,
   title: myMapInfo[i].name
  });
  
  // Allow each marker to have an info window    
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
  return function() {
   infoWindow.setContent('<div class=\"myInfoHead\"><a href=\"/caravan-parks/type/View/id/' + myMapInfo[i].id + '\">' + myMapInfo[i].name + '</a></div>');
   infoWindow.open(map, marker);
  }
  })(marker, i));
  
 }
 var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
 for (var i = 0; i < myMapInfo.length; i++) {
  latlngbounds.extend(myMapInfo[i].latlng);
 }

latlngbounds.extend( new google.maps.LatLng(-38.032345,145.343456) ); //add Berwick Vic to the latlngbounds for top padding

 map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

////draw a rectangle of the latlngbounds - handy for debuging
 //new google.maps.Rectangle({
 //    bounds: latlngbounds,
 //    map: map,
 //    fillColor: "#000000",
 //    fillOpacity: 0.2,
 //    strokeWeight: 0
 //});

}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', map_initialize);
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height:500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone else having this issue you just need to override Google's default css like this:

```
.gm-style-iw{
    height: 100% !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    width: auto !important;
}
```

Important Note: You will also need to make sure that you use the correct javascript url..

CORRECT URL:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3"></script>
```

INCORRECT URL (which is unfortunately used on Google's api pages - https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp"></script>
```

Comment: The "incorrect URL" is the experimental version.  If there are issues with that, and they aren't identified, eventually that version will become the release version, and your "fix" will stop working.

Comment: I'm aware that that it is the experimental version & that's why it should not be used on a live site or in the google api docs as most people just copy & paste them..